# How to query recent items in mac os x?

Tags: macos, api

I understand, in Mac OS X, system-wide the OS keeps tracks of a list of recent opened items (files) (click the Apple Icon, and click "Recent Items". But I would like to obtain this list so that it can be used for other purposes. Is it possible to have API to query such items or has it been actually stored in a file locally (if so, where is the location)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stored in:

```
/Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems.plist
```

It's a binary property list file, so you can view its contents in XCode, or use /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy in Terminal, or use property list API's.

Here's a Bash script that will dump all the recent documents in alpha order.

```
docCount=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print RecentDocuments:MaxAmount" \
  ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems.plist)
for (( i=0; i<docCount; i++ )); do
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print RecentDocuments:CustomListItems:$i:Name" \
      ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems.plist
done | sort
```

Comment: Thanks! I also wonder is there a way to just find those "mostly recent modified files" by a command or API?

Comment: If I may, May i ask what does the "bookmark" and "sharedfilelist.binding" mean? they are raw data for the directory of those items? or ASCII codes..thx

Comment: I updated my answer to provide a script to display the recent items. As for other fields, I don't know what's in them, though the path to the file appears to be within Bookmark.

Answer (score 2):

This has changed in El Cap, per http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/8122-use-alfred-to-observe-contents-of-all-my-files/

> Pre-El Capitan, there was a plist file at "~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems.plist" containing the data you're after.
>
> In El Capitan, you can get the list of paths with the shell command:

```
mdfind -onlyin $HOME '((kMDItemContentModificationDate > $time.now(-60m)) && (kMDItemContentModificationDate < $time.now()))' | grep -v /Library/
```

> (This excludes files in "~/Library".)